# Question about this specific proof of $\forall a\in G$ $aH=Ha$ implies $H$ is normal

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, proof-writing, normal-subgroups

I've just tried to come up with a proof of the above statement but I feel like something is not quite right. The question I have *isn't* about proving the statement, I've found that in lots of places, but rather about this particular proof.

---

Firstly we can define a normal subgroup $H$ (of $G$) to satisfy:
$$ \forall a\in G \;\forall h\in H\;\;\;\; aha^{-1}\in H $$
This is what I tried: $ \forall a\in G\; aH=Ha  $ means that $x\in aH \iff x\in Ha$ so from $x\in aH$:
$$ \forall x\in aH\; \exists h\in H :x=ah\; \rightarrow\;xa^{-1}=aha^{-1} (\in H \text{ from below reasoning})$$
where we can show that $xa^{-1}$ is in $H$ using similar logic from the fact that $x$ is also in $Ha$.

---

The problem I have is I'm wondering whether I've actually shown that the subgroup is normal since the definition of it being normal requires a '$\forall h\in H$' (the $\forall a\in G$ is already in the proof) whereas the way I showed it only found that $h$ *exists* rather than showing it works for *every* $h$. I thought maybe it was bound up in $\forall x\in aH$ but I can't seem to concretely get at it. Or maybe there's something wrong with my understanding somewhere (either with the proof writing or group theory).

---

**Added:**

I've just been thinking about it a little. If we have $\forall x\in aH \;\exists h\in H:x=ah$ then surely, for a fixed $a$, all of the $h$'s (that correspond to a particular element, $x$, in the coset) must be unique since you can't have two elements equal in the same coset (and since $a$ is fixed it must be the $h$ that's changing). The order of $aH$ is the same as the order of $H$ so that surely means all the $h$'s in $H$ are 'used' in the above proof so it would be $\forall h\in H$ for that fixed $a$ (or another way might be to see the map $H\rightarrow aH$ defined by $h\mapsto ah$ is bijective). Then when you vary $a$ the same reasoning applies so you get the $\forall a\in G\; \forall h \in H $. I know this isn't the most efficient way to prove this, it's more to help my understanding (which hopefully my above reasoning explains why I think it should work) than wanting to prove it.

Comment: For all $h\in H$ and $a\in G$, we have that $ha\in aH$, and therefore $ha = ak$ for some $k\in H$.  Then multiply by $a^{-1}$ on the left.

Comment: @JonathanLamar  that's a much nicer way to show it. I was just wondering why the route I took didn't work, or if it does work, how to show it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I understand your question:
Suppose we know that
$$\forall a \in G\,\forall x \in aH\exists h\in H:x=ah\wedge aha^{-1}\in H\qquad\qquad (*)$$
can we deduce
$$\forall a \in G\,\forall h\in H:aha^{-1}\in H.$$
The answer is (of course) yes. Let $a \in G$ and let $h \in H$, then $ah$ is in $aH$ and hence by $(*)$ there exist $h'$ is in $H$ such that $ah=ah'$ and $ah'a^{-1}$ is in $H$, but this means that $h=a^{-1}ah=a^{-1}ah'=h'$ and hence $aha^{-1}$ is in $H$ as desired.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I realise that the question was quite confusing/pedantic. It just confused me how you could get from where I got $(*)$ to incorporating the '$\forall h \in H$' into the proof, which your answer makes clear. I don't think it helped that I tried to get from one definition to the other so rigidly, it seems to be much better to construct them like in your answer, or how the comment to question did. Thanks for the help! :)